# no module named portaudio aws lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio, portaudio

I currently have some python code that I have stored in a zip file with my dependencies. The code compiles and works fine locally in Visual Studio Code. However, when I go to upload the file onto a Lambda function, I get this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named '_portaudio'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I am using pyaudio and I have never had any interaction with portaudio. What should I do?

Attached is a screenshot of my zip file:
[image: Screenshot]

**Image Updates**

[image: New Lambda Layer]

[image: Zip File]

Comment: server may not have audio hardware so portaudio can be useless on server.

Comment: server may run `Linux` but your `portaudio` can be only for `Windows`